# How do I get the value of the dependent source in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJJKZN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm very confused, since they are in parallel wouldn't the voltage of \$R_1\$ be equal to the voltage of \$R_2\$ and is also equal to the current dependent voltage source \$10I_x\$. However, to get \$I_x\$, its \$Ix = 10I_x/50\$ which would cancel out \$I_x\$, thus not getting \$I_x\$?

Comment: No independent source is present in the circuit thus Ix = 0

Comment: I've edited the circuit now to have an independent source, but my argument is still the same i think

Comment: Yes, Ix is still equal to 0A.

Comment: can i ask why is that so? Is it because the voltage source would just go through the short wire, not going through R2 thus not giving current to the dependent source?

Comment: Because you have a current dependent current source whose value is not fixed but rather which depends on some other circuit current (Ix in this case).  So to get any "output" from a dependent source the Ix current must be flowing in the first place.

Comment: @G36 Isn't that an unstable solution though?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany No, there is no source of "noise" in circuit theory.

Comment: Excuse me, but the questioner draws and writes different things. He has drawn a voltage controlled voltage source and writes something else. What should be believed? BTW the right half of the edited circuit doesn't interact with the left half. The vertical wire at the right end of R3 prevents it.

Comment: @user287001 That was the very first thing I just noticed, dropping in here just now. Your other point is also correct.  I'll edit and fix that dependent source.